Why does the scrollbar value keep resetting to 0?
I have implemented a feature in my game where users can scroll horizontally between 5 pages. The third page is the middle one, so I want to set the starting page to the third page. However, the scrollbar's value keeps resetting to 0.


Even if I set the value to 0.5 in the Inspector and start the game, it reverts back to 0 after stopping the game. Restarting the Unity Editor or reloading the scene also causes the value to reset to 0. I would appreciate any advice on why this is happening and how to fix it.

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

@DarkBee My question is about a situation, not code, so no code is needed for an answer.

Are you sure this is a programming-related question then? From the tag's excerpt: "Questions should be about programming with the game engine and not usage of the graphical interface. Questions about the usage of the graphics interface are off topic."

@DarkBee My question is indeed programming-related, as it involves scripting in Unity to control the behavior of a UI component (the scrollbar). The issue is that the scrollbar value keeps resetting, which I want to resolve through code. This is not about using the graphical interface itself, but about programmatically managing the UI element's state during runtime, which falls under programming with the game engine.

If so, where is the relevant code for this problem? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? [ask]

I can't provide the code for Unity's built-in components, as they are part of the engine and not accessible

If the question is not related to code, you need to share the scene. It's difficult for us to pinpoint the issue from 2 pictures.

Then I will upload a recording of the scene.

FYI: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com is also a worthwhile place to explore your problem

https://streamable.com/myy88r
Here is my video

To share the scene, you can copy the content of the scene file (.unity). If it is made with built-in components, then I can reproduce the scene with it.

I think the ScrollRect will be overruling the settings you made directly on the Scrollbar component.
Rather try and set the ScrollRect.normalizedPosition instead - e.g. like
void Start()
{
    GetComponent<Scrollrect>().normalizedPosition = new Vector2(0.5f, 0f);
}


Alternatively afaik you can also directly overrule the position of the content - so if you want to center it on the ScrollRect you could also do e.g.
contentTransform.position = scrollRectTransform.position;

